# Unexpected token while saving virtual dataset from SQL Query in Apache Superset

Tags: dataset, apache-superset

I am having issue while saving my virtual dataset through sql query. It's showing unexpected token.
please help in solving this error. I am performing join on two tables from the database, and I need the queried data to draw the chart. But I ma unable to save this dataset for further process
[Unexpected Token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roMD6.jpg)

I tried on different browsers, but the issue persist.